# PHP - Zend - httpd (no pid file) not running on Mac

Tags: php, macos, apache, zend-framework, httpd.conf

My Mac OS is OS X El Capitan

I am not getting http://localhost/

```
httpd -v
```

gives

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)
```

and

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

gives

```
httpd not running, trying to start
/usr/local/zend/bin/apachectl restart [OK]
```

and

```
sudo /usr/local/zend/bin/zendctl.sh restart
```

gives

```
Stopping Deployment [OK]
Starting Deployment [OK]
[19.01.2016 12:06:20 SYSTEM] watchdog for zdd is running. 
[19.01.2016 12:06:20 SYSTEM] zdd is running. 
Stopping Zend Server Monitor node [OK]
Starting Zend Server Monitor node [OK]
[19.01.2016 12:06:27 SYSTEM] watchdog for monitor is running. 
[19.01.2016 12:06:27 SYSTEM] monitor is running. 
httpd (no pid file) not running
/usr/local/zend/bin/apachectl stop [OK]
/usr/local/zend/bin/apachectl start [OK]
Stopping Zend Server GUI [Lighttpd] [OK]
spawn-fcgi: child signaled: 5
Starting Zend Server GUI [Lighttpd] [OK]
Stopping Java bridge [OK]
Starting Java bridge [OK]
Stopping JobQueue [OK]
Starting JobQueue [OK]
[19.01.2016 12:06:43 SYSTEM] watchdog for jqd is running. 
[19.01.2016 12:06:43 SYSTEM] jqd is running.
```

In the above, you can see that httpd (no pid file) not running

How can I fix this?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: First use `ps ax` to see if httpd is running or not.  If it is, maybe it just can't write into the pidfile dirrectory (often `/var/run`).  If it is not running, check its `error_log` file for why (probably something amiss in its config file).